# How to avoid Duplicate Entry DB errors that have appeared when I switched to Spork for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

I just started using Spork and my tests are producing random "duplicate entry" errors from the DB. I assume this has something to do with a change in the way the DB is flushed between tests? How can I fix this?

These errors did not surface before Spork...

Comment: post your testing config, like spec_helper.rb if you are using rspec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like Database Cleaner (https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner/)